# Does Netspeeder can speed up Tor service?

Tags: configuration, speed

This is netspeeder's website:https://github.com/iMeiji/shadowsocks_install/wiki/Net-Speeder

This is the installing command line for Ubuntu and Debian:
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iMeiji/shadowsocks_install/master/debian_netspeeder_tennfy.sh
chmod a+x debian_netspeeder_tennfy.sh
bash debian_netspeeder_tennfy.sh

Does it can speed up Tor? It can speed up some services such as Shadowsocks.

Answer (score 1):

No. If it doesn't end up causing a higher error rate/connection issues it still wouldn't net you a noticeable change with your TOR connection rates or overall speed.

The tool is made to make already poor connections act more stable and it's optimized to be used alongside tools like shadowstocks.

Below is noted from past experience.

Netspeeder caused freenet to become unstable/almost unusable due to consistently dropped/rejected connections. When it was stable it ran at the same average speed I noted prior to introducing netspeeder.

*Admittedly this is an assumption solely due to notes when using it alongside freenets network I have not tested it with TOR's network but I'd assume the same issues would occur and at the least it would effectively have little to no bearing on speed if it actually does not have issues as adding lanes to a tunnel doesn't improve the speedlimit just the traffic potential (as well as error rate)*

Comment: But,I run it with Tor and Obfs4 bridge, my brige work normally.I haven't found any error but I don't know it change speed or not too

Comment: And,does Google BBR:https://github.com/google/bbr can speed up Tor or Obfs4 bridge? It can speed up shadowstocks too

Comment: I'd refer to the lanes in a tunnel reference here... technically though. bbr could potentially be used to lighten loads on the host end... based on how it appears to be scripted. Unfortunately I can only theorize the potential use as I have no first hand knowledge with bbr. As a multi-lane tool it should fall under the same category as the OP listed tool...

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand more words about program.Can you answer strightly that BBR can speed up bridges and Tor serive or not? Please